# Como limitar o Drag e Drop apenas a determinadas views?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de saber se consigo controlar o que entra em meu layout (DROP)
Pois das image view abaixo eu gostaria que apenas a "imgu" pudesse entrar no meu layout, o restante não:

```
findViewById(R.id.imga).setOnLongClickListener(new MyOnLongClickListener());
    findViewById(R.id.imge).setOnLongClickListener(new MyOnLongClickListener());
    findViewById(R.id.imgi).setOnLongClickListener(new MyOnLongClickListener());
    findViewById(R.id.imgo).setOnLongClickListener(new MyOnLongClickListener());
    findViewById(R.id.imgu).setOnLongClickListener(new MyOnLongClickListener());

    findViewById(R.id.layoutrecebe).setOnDragListener( new MyOnDragListener(1));
```

Answer (score 2):

No método `onDrag()`, da sua implementação do OnDragListener, verifique se o id da view recebida é aquela que quer, caso não seja retorne `false`:

```
@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {

    if(v.getId() != R.id.imgu) return false;
    ...
    ...
}
```